# Field extensions and algebraic elements

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

[image]

Can somebody explain why taking beta gives $K(\beta)$ as a subspace of $K(\alpha)$?

Comment: Because it is generated by elements $\beta^i$ which are themselves polynomials in $\alpha$ ?

Comment: It's a subset, and it's a field, so it's a subfield, so it's a subspace.

Comment: Nothing in the question suggested that the fields would be finite, so I removed that tag. use43290, if that is a mistake, please add the fact that $L$ and $K$ are finite (sets/fields) to the listed assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the definition of $K(\beta)$ being the smallest field that contains $\beta$:

> If $\beta \in K(\alpha)$, then
>
> $$K(\beta)= \bigcap_{\substack{F \ \ \text{field} \\ \beta\in F}}F\subseteq K(\alpha)$$